# Importar Planilha Excell XLS e gravar em banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

OBS: Primeiramente desculpa alguma ignorância, mas sou iniciante e não compreendo de forma avançada PHP e SQL

PROBLEMA:

Eu tenho algumas planilhas onde recebo algumas informações, que são atualizadas a cada 6 horas. 
A dificuldade principal é quando eu preciso comparar alguma informação entre as últimas 2,3 planilhas por exemplo, pois preciso abrir uma e depois a outra e ver os valores, etc..

Eu gostaria de importar e gravar essas informações em um banco MySQL, pois ai eu consigo manipular melhor as informações.

IDEIA INICIAL:

Criar um banco MySQL e uma tabela especifica com as mesmas colunas da planilha, ADICIONANDO algumas colunas extras e gravar as informações nesse banco. 
Porém por falta de conhecimento avançado em PHP e SQL, não encontrei a melhor forma de fazer esse processo.

Até encontrei alguns exemplo mas eram um pouco complexos e não consegui compreender.

Exemplo:
Resumo da estrutura da TABELA no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo: 
Preciso importar o arquivo XLS e salvar no banco, inserindo algumas colunas que não estão presentes no arquivo.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: @ChristianFelipe , por hora nada além de teste de INPUT e INSERT simples, estava vendo os exemplos que encontrei. Então não postei nada pra ver os exemplo e ideias de que tem experiência pra eu fazer da melhor forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode se conectar à planilha XLS através de uma conexão ODBC, exemplo:

```
$excel = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq={$caminhoComplePlanilhaXLS};DefaultDir=C:\\" , '', '');
```

Feito isso você terá a variável `$excel` com o resource da conexão, então pode consultar os dados da planilha como se fosse uma tabela de banco de dados, exemplo:

```
$sel = 'Select * from [MinhaPlanilha$A1:D500]';
$rs = odbc_exec($excel, $sel);

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
   $col1 = odbc_result($rs, 1);
   $col2 = odbc_result($rs, 2);
}
```

Esta é uma forma bem simples... Se não for assim recomendo utilizar o [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).